# Allocating with new and storing in LRU buffer, deletion does not happen?

Tags: c++, caching, memory-management, new-operator

I am implementing a simple cache of unordered maps allocating them with the `new` keyword, and I would like for the objects to be deleted when they are evicted from the cache. For reference, this is the LRU cache implementation I am using: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/util/concurrent-lru-cache.h

I am testing my program on Linux, 1 thread. The code is the following:

```
HPHP::ConcurrentLRUCache<std::string, std::unordered_map<int, int>*> my_cache(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    auto map = new std::unordered_map<int, int>(1000);
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        map->insert(std::make_pair(j, j));
    my_cache.insert(std::to_string(i), map);
}

template <class TKey, class TValue, class THash>
    bool ConcurrentLRUCache<TKey, TValue, THash>::
    insert(const TKey& key, const TValue& value) {
        // Insert into the CHM
        ListNode* node = new ListNode(key);
        HashMapAccessor hashAccessor;
        HashMapValuePair hashMapValue(key, HashMapValue(value, node));
        if (!m_map.insert(hashAccessor, hashMapValue)) {
            delete node;
            return false;
        }

        // Evict if necessary, now that we know the hashmap insertion was successful.
        size_t size = m_size.load();
        bool evictionDone = false;
        if (size >= m_maxSize) {
            evict();
            evictionDone = true;
        }

        std::unique_lock<ListMutex> lock(m_listMutex);
        pushFront(node);
        lock.unlock();
        if (!evictionDone) {
            size = m_size++;
        }
        if (size > m_maxSize) {
            if (m_size.compare_exchange_strong(size, size - 1)) {
                evict();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

template <class TKey, class TValue, class THash>
    void ConcurrentLRUCache<TKey, TValue, THash>::
    evict() {
        std::unique_lock<ListMutex> lock(m_listMutex);
        ListNode* moribund = m_tail.m_prev;
        if (moribund == &m_head) {
            // List is empty, can't evict
            return;
        }
        delink(moribund);
        lock.unlock();

        HashMapAccessor hashAccessor;
        if (!m_map.find(hashAccessor, moribund->m_key)) {
            // Presumably unreachable
            return;
        }
        m_map.erase(hashAccessor);
        delete moribund;
    }
```

When inserting a map, if the cache is full, the last recently used element should get evicted. However, the map itself does not get deleted and the memory usage peaks. What am I doing wrong?

Note: the maps should be retrieved during the execution of my program, so they should be accessible from the cache.

Comment: One rarely needs pointers to standard containers. If you have a vector of your maps, then you don't need pointers or your own explicit dynamic allocation. Let the vector handle it. Also, one rarely needs to set the bucket count for an unordered map. Are you sure you know what it implies when creating the maps with `1000` buckets?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" you are using raw owning pointers. Use smart pointers to manage lifetime. Or why not simply use `std::unordered_map<int, int>` rather than pointers?

Comment: And about the dynamic parts of storage for the maps, it seems you have made your own list. Why? If you want a list, what's wrong with `std::list` or `std::forward_list`? Or, indeed, `std::vector`? If you use `std::vector` and are worried about its reallocations, that will likely not be a big issue considering the move-semantics of the standard containers. Or you could just reserve memory in the vector if you know how many elements it's supposed to contain.

Comment: Yes I know what it means to allocate buckets (this was just an example) and I am using the list coming with the implementation I am using which is not made by myself. I do not need advice on these things. The main reason why I am using new here is that I am concerned about the lifetime of my maps, won't they be deleted as soon as the for loop terminates? I am going to try now with smart pointers, please let me know if you have any suggestion on how to properly implement them

Comment: The life-time of locally scoped objects will end when the scope they were defined in ends, that's correct. *But* you can still copy (or *move*) objects so that's seldom an issue.

Comment: `evict` deletes the ListNode. Where does it delete the value? Does it delete the value?

Comment: Ended up storing the maps themselves in cache, instead of the pointers. However, when doing this, I lose information about the bucket counts, ie if I store a map of 5k buckets and only 10 elements, the map gets retrieved with 10 buckets (or whatever formula cpp implements to calculate the optimal value). I think this is due to the maps being copied somewhere. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Nevermind, the bucket problem is related to the implementation of map I am using and does not concern std::map